# How to split value from mysql query in php

Tags: mysql, arrays, split, field

i'm a newbie in php and Mysql.
I've got a table called 'cat_filter' done like this

```
cat_filter_id   cat_filter_value    cat_filter_name               categories_id

5   Colore Metallo      Bianco                              13
2   Tipologia Schienale Rete                                11
3   Finiture            Cromata                             11
4   Tipologia Poltrona  Direzionale;Operativa;Visitatori    11
```

I've done this code :

```
$connessione=mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password);
mysql_select_db($db_database,$connessione);     
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cat_filter WHERE categories_id=$current_category_id") or die(mysql_error());  echo '<p>';
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
echo ''.$info['cat_filter_value'] . ': <a href="index.php?main_page=advanced_search_result&keyword='.$info['cat_filter_name'] . '&search_in_description=1&categories_id='.$current_category_id . '">'.$info['cat_filter_name'] . '</a> ~ ';
}
echo '</p>';
mysql_close();
```

The works quite well, but i'd like taht if a field has more value separeted by this ';' the output will be separated for each (sorry for my english) .. is it clear ?
Thanx in advance !
best regards.
Francesco

Answer (score 1):

Change the `echo '' . $info['cat_filter_value']` line to perform a loop:

```
foreach (explode(';', $info['cat_filter_value']) as $value) {
    echo $value . ": ...";
}
```

Comment: I've added your code ... last question. Is it possibile to print only once cat filter value ?
Exemple : i've 
cat_filter_value 'Value1'  
cat_filter_name  'Name1;Name2;Name3'

I'd like to print : Value1 : <a link with Name1>Name1</a> - <a link with Name2>Name2</a> - <a link with Name3>Name3</a>

In this moment i have:
 Value1 : <a link with Name1>Name1</a> - Value1 : <a link with Name2>Name2</a> - Value1 : <a link with Name3>Name3</a>

I hope ive been clear. Thanx in advance again.